# Problem in Nested Routing in Angular Modules

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have a problem in routing with Angular. I wanted to put the login on `/login` and I did it successfully. My problem is that I wanted to put the Register page on `/register`

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { PrivateLayoutComponent } from './core/layouts/private/private-layout.component';
import { PublicLayoutComponent } from './core/layouts/public/public-layout.component';
import { privateRoutes } from './core/routes/private-layout.routes';
import { publicRoutes } from './core/routes/public-layout.routes';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: '',
    component: PrivateLayoutComponent,
    children: privateRoutes,
  },
  { path: '', component: PublicLayoutComponent, children: publicRoutes },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**public-layout.routes.ts**

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

// Route for content layout without sidebar, navbar and footer for pages like Login, Registration etc...
export const publicRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('@app/auth/auth.module').then((m) => m.AuthModule),
  },
];
```

**auth-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'forgot-password', component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AuthRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want `/register` to be a route just like `/login`, you have a few options:

1. Create another module for the register functionality and lazy load it just like you do with `AuthModule`.
2. Stop lazy loading the `AuthModule` and declare your login and register routes in the `AppRoutingModule` directly.

The `RegisterComponent` can be found on the `/login/register` path though.

Comment: Yeah whats your recommened solution, the best way? one or two?

Comment: Easiest would be to stop lazy loading the `AuthModule` and import it in your `AppModule` instead. The split of the `AuthModule` into `LoginModule` and `RegisterModule` implies more work (check what's common between them, maybe introduce a new module with shared code, etc). It's your choice at the end of the day :).

Comment: Is lazy loading recommended to avoid size? I dont need to lazy load only the dashboard which the app loads when the app opens.

Answer (score -1):

you can redirect to the registration page with the `/login/register` path.

For a clean approach follow the steps

- In **public-layout.routes.ts**

  - rename path to `path: 'auth'`
- In **auth-routing.module.ts**

  - Update Routes array

```
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: "login", component: LoginComponent },
      { path: "register", component: RegisterComponent },
      { path: "forgot-password", component: ForgotPasswordComponent },
    ];
```

- Now you can access the routes with `/auth/login`, `/auth/register` and `/auth/something`

Comment: I know i can do this but I dont want /auth